# Resize an Image that has been uploaded as multipart/form-data in a WebAPI controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am getting an image which has been uploaded to a Web API method using `multipart/form-data` using `await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider)` as follows:

```
// Read the form data.
await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

foreach (MultipartFileData item in provider.FileData)
{
    string name = item.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", "");
    newFileName = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(name);
    File.Move(item.LocalFileName, Path.Combine(rootPath, newFileName));
    Uri baseuri = new Uri(Request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.Replace(Request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery, string.Empty));
    string fileRelativePath = rootPath + newFileName;
    Uri fileFullPath = new Uri(baseuri, VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(fileRelativePath));
    savedFilePath.Add(fileFullPath.ToString());
    Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dictionary.Add(fieldID, newFileName);
    HttpContext.Current.Session[fieldID] = dictionary;
}
```

I need to resize the image before saving it to disk. I am not sure if I can do this at run-time. Any Ideas?